# Form a select query in Javascript step and need to execute the query in pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have a situation where I need to form a select query in Modified Java Script Value step and pass that query to run in a database.

I can successfully form the query and I have trouble in running the query and getting back the query result.

I tried Database join step since it is complete query it cannot run it. Please guide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. '**Modified Java Script Value**' Step executes for each row. I'm assuming It is receiving at least 1 row. If Not, Then '**Generate Rows**' can be used.
2. Make sure the generated query string reaches next step (Preview data view)
3. Use '**Dynamic SQL row**' Step to execute SQL :

   - Specify the field which holds generated query in previous step and Number of rows to retrieve ('0' to retrieve all rows)
   - Specify the Static Template SQL to retrieve metadata

> Example:
>
> > **Query** : SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname = 'pg_catalog';
> > **Template SQL** : SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;

Using Template SQL, The PDI will determine SQL Resultset structure (Metadata).

[image]

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!